# Conjecture about a finest equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I've thought about finest equivalence relations and came up with a conjecture but I am neither able to prove nor able to disprove it. A hint would be great.

Be $M$ a set, be $f$ a bijective function with $f: M \rightarrow M$ and be $\sim$ the finest equivalence relation on the set $M$ with $x \sim f(x)$ for all $x \in M$.

Be also $Z$ a set and $g$ a surjective function with $g: M \rightarrow Z$ and $\forall x \in M: g(x) = g(f(x))$

> Does this imply: $$\forall x,y \in M: x \sim y \implies g(x) = g(y)$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a relation $\approx$ on $M$ by $x \approx y$ if $g(x) = g(y)$.

Can you see that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation on $M$ and that $x \approx f(x)$ for all $x \in M$?

Comment: Hello Zoe, yes, but I do not know how to go on from there... I have to show that $x \sim y$ with $g(x) \neq g(y)$ creates a contradiction since $\sim$ is the finest equivalence relation, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: @swizzor $\sim$ is the finest equivalence relation with the property that $x \sim f(x)$ for all $x \in M$, so $\sim$ must be finer that $\approx$.

Comment: Well, to be honest that was the first thing I tried but I thought it would be a circular argument since this is exactly $x \sim y \implies g(x) = g(x)$, but sure, that is just the definition of 'finest equivalence relation'

Comment: The claims for $f$ to be bijective and for $g$ to be surjective are not necessary, right?

Comment: @swizzor Yes, those assumptions are not necessary.